# Repeated measures approach or not?

Tags: repeated-measures, mixed-model

The basic question here is whether the following situation would warrant a repeated measures approach with a mixed effects model or not.

Let's say I have a set of grocery stores in 5 different geographic regions and I am evaluating the effects of 3 interventions on customer wait time for a cashier. The stores are randomly assigned into the 3 intervention groups (somewhat uniformly distributed across the states) and all or most customers will experience the designated intervention at each store. The basic question is which intervention works best to reduce customer wait time. What I'm wondering is if this is actually a repeated measures design where each store can be considered a "subject" and I then account for between-subject heterogeneity. And what might be good ways of demonstrating correlation of observed wait times within each store?

Since there is clustering, I'm leaning towards a mixed effects model.

Comment: (1) Do you have before & after measurements, or at least multiple measurements, for each store?  (2) Significant correlation of wait times within stores is equivalent to finding a significant among-store variance ...

Comment: Yes, there is before and after measures for each store and also multiple measurements for each store.

Comment: then my answer is "yes".